# High reputation in Christianity, low reputation in Islam - possible warning sign?

Tags: discussion

I received an answer from [someone](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/8589/bruised-reed) who has a high reputation in Christianity.SE, but hasn't been active on Islam.SE, and therefore has a low reputation here.

Should I be worried that such a user may be biased in favour of Christianity, and have a bias against Islam?

Comment: See also: [How do I write a good answer to a question?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/610/138)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not.  If any given answer actually *does* turn out to be unfairly biassed against Islam, voting <strike>will</strike> should sort it out.  Unless you're seeing posts that are both *clearly* against Islam *and* being heavily upvoted, I don't think there's anything to worry about; people are allowed to be knowledgeable in more than one topic, after all.

And if you *are* seeing posts that are both *clearly* against Islam *and* being heavily upvoted, feel free to flag them for moderator attention.